# De-serialize JSON Data in Android

Tags: android, json, deserialization

I have the following data and I am asked to de-serialize it. But how to de-serialize the following json data?

```
"drug": "a:1:{s:6:\"drug_0\";a:3:{s:11:\"drug_name_0\";s:4:\"Napa\";s:13:\"drug_dosage_0\";d:1;s:15:\"drug_duration_0\";d:1;}}"
```

Comment: Use http://jsonlint.com/ to verify your json. This json doesn't seem correct to me.

Comment: Is my solution useful ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is incorrect. This should be the correct JSON

```
String json = "{\"drug\": \"a:1:{s:6:\\\"drug_0\\\";a:3:{s:11:\\\"drug_name_0\\\";s:4:\\\"Napa\\\";s:13:\\\"drug_dosage_0\\\";d:1;s:15:\\\"drug_duration_0\\\";d:1;}}\"}";
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
String drug = jsonObject.getString("drug");
```

Using this you can get value of `drug` as `a:1:{s:6:\"drug_0\";a:3:{s:11:\"drug_name_0\";s:4:\"Napa\";s:13:\"drug_dosage_0\";d:1;s:15:\"drug_duration_0\";d:1;}}`

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to do something like this:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject("your json string");
```

and from there get primitives or nested json jbjects by calling methods such as: `getInt()`, `getString()`, `getJSONObject()`.